# <li> elements won´t align vertically in mobile version

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, alignment

I´m trying to get my icons to vertically align with the text it belongs to in the mobile view of my website. The elements are set to vertical-align:middle and so on but nothing seems to help...

It can be seen on for example www.niklaskoskela.com/hkr.html

It´s the list that explains what time the project took place and so on.

I dont have enough points to post images yet so I can´t show exactly what it looks like.

I would appreciate any help I could get.

Have no idea how to make a JSFiddle

HTML:

```
<div class="info">
<ul>
 <li>
  <img src="img/skills.png" alt="skills">
 </li>
 <li>
  <h3>GRAPHIC DESIGN, INTERFACE DESIGN</h3> 
 </li>
</ul>   
<ul>
 <li>
  <img src="img/period.png" alt="period">
 </li>
 <li>
  <h3>OCT 2013 - JAN 2014</h3>
 </li>
</ul>
<ul>
 <li>
  <img src="img/website.png" alt="project website">
 </li>
 <li>
  <a href="http://www.hkr.se" target="_blank">
  <h3>WWW.HKR.SE</h3></a>
 </li>
</ul>       
</div>
```

CSS:

@media screen and (max-device-width: 960px){

```
.info{

    float: left;
    padding-bottom: 5%;
    width: 95%;
    padding-left: 5%;

}

.info ul{

    display: block;
    list-style: none;
    width: 93%;

}

.info ul li{

    list-style-type: none;
    vertical-align: middle;
    left: 0;

}

.info ul li img{

    width: 35%;
    height: auto;
    display: inline;

}

.info ul li a{

    color: #6dc4c8;

}

.info ul li a:hover{

    text-decoration: none;
    color: #cc7e47;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #cc7e47;

}

.info ul li h3{

    float: right;
    display: inline-block;
    font-family: 'Quicksand';
    color: #7a7a7a;
    font-size: 3em;
    font-weight: 400;
    width: 65%;

}
```

Regards

Comment: HTML& CSS in a JSFiddle please

Comment: you should add display:inline-block to make sense of a rule vertical-align

Comment: make a paint image that explain what you have and what you are looking for at least. However check if any css resetter it's modyifing something you need

Comment: added inline-block but didn´t get any effect

Comment: If that css is inside an @media screen statement then it will only be triggered by desktop class computers.
*Edit at least it is supposed to. I've had better luck using a straight screen size declaration to distinguish.

Comment: yeah, all I am looking at the moment is how it looks from the phone. I want it to look same as when I view from laptop but end up underneath the summary of one project. Instead the text connected to the icons keep ending up in random places and not aligned at all...

Answer (score 1):

wHEN YOU NEED VERTICAL ALIGNMENT OF ELEMENTS. fOR EXAMPLE IMG AND TEXT YOU SHOULD USE THIS CODE:

**HTML**

```
<div class="info">
    <ul class="list">
        <li>
            <div class="img-holder"><img src="images/img-31.jpg" alt="image description"/></div>
            <h3>GRAPHIC DESIGN, INTERFACE DESIGN</h3>
        </li>
        <li>
            <div class="img-holder"><img src="img/period.png" alt="image description"/></div>
            <h3>OCT 2013 - JAN 2014</h3>
        </li>
        <li>
            <div class="img-holder"><img src="img/website.png" alt="project website"></div>
            <h3>WWW.HKR.SE</h3>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
       .list {
        margin:0;
        padding:0;
        list-style:none;
    }
    .list li {
        width: 100%;
        overflow: hidden;
        margin: 0 0 15px;
    }
    .list .img-holder {
        display: inline-block;
        vertical-align: middle;
/*the sum of this elements should be less than 100% it is due to 3px bug*/
        width: 18%; 

    }
    .list .img-holder img {
        max-width: 100%;
        height: auto;
    }
    .list h3 {
        display: inline-block;
        vertical-align: middle;
        width: 80%;
        margin: 0;
    }
```

Try to adapt this code for yourself

Comment: The thing is that it works perfectly on the web version, it´s just in the mobile view that it messes up..

Comment: perhaps you need to hardcode the width of text block - but use only %

Comment: I have it set to 65% at the moment and the img set to 35% but the text ends up underneath and is positioned in an unordered manner (wherever it feels like..)

Comment: Thank you so much! However, it does the same as my first solution when I view it from my laptop but is still messed up on the phone. All I´m looking for is a solution for when it´s viewed from the phone, to look the same as on the laptop. I changed some bits in the code you wrote but still couldn´t get it to work. I am not experienced enough in HTML and CSS it seems...

Answer (score 0):

Your UL-Tag is not wide enough. It's responsive shrunking with the screenWidth. You need to give it a minimum size of 353 px and it will work but will cuase some other trouble you have to fix.

```
.info ul {
display: block;
list-style: none;
padding-top: 5%;
min-width: 353px;}
```

Comment: I tried this but it didn´t change anything unfortunately. Thanks though

Comment: did you try to figure it with testing with the browsers-element-inspectors (firebug etc) and resizing the window? For me the min-width was the solution. 
Otherwise you could maybe scale down the font-size. You don't need the same size as on PC-screens